# Flutter package get not working for stripe plugins only

Tags: plugins, dart, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to include stripe plugin and when I am adding in pubsec.yml nothing happens when import in the file getting an error... I created a new project and import plugin but same thing happening other plugins working file.

[image]

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.285], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

It imports but still giving plugin missing error:

```
E/flutter ( 4388): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 4388): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getCardToken on channel com.mtaliaf.stripeflutter/stripe_flutter)
E/flutter ( 4388): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:278:7)
E/flutter ( 4388): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4388): #1      StripeFlutter.getCardToken (package:stripe_flutter/stripe_flutter.dart:16:41)
E/flutter ( 4388): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4388): #2      _CheckcodeState.initPlatformState (package:ecom_hybrid/ui/check_code.dart:31:39)
E/flutter ( 4388): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4388): #3      _CheckcodeState.initState (package:ecom_hybrid/ui/check_code.dart:22:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3763:58)
E/flutter ( 4388): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3629:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3665:16)
E/flutter ( 4388): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3507:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3634:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3629:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3665:16)
E/flutter ( 4388): #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3507:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3634:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3781:11)
E/flutter ( 4388): #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3629:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3665:16)
E/flutter ( 4388): #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3507:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #38     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3634:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3629:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2919:14)
E/flutter ( 4388): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2722:12)
E/flutter ( 4388): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3665:16)
E/flutter ( 4388): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3507:5)
E/flutter ( 4388): #44     Comp
```

Comment: I've had this occur occasionally is visual studio code with other packages. Make sure you've saved all, then manually type the import. For some reason it sometimes ignores the import when I cut and paste. No idea why.

Comment: Also try to run `flutter packages get` in terminal and see if it gives you error.

Comment: when i am trying manually it imports but still getting missing plugin error. Meanwhile thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I am editing my question with error please check above message.

Comment: this might seem trivial but just to make sure, have you tried closing the project and reopening?

Comment: Also, the error in your lib folder is it solely coming from the dart file that contains the import or are there other errors?

Comment: I just restarted my project now it's working fine...Thanks! You saved my lots time.

Comment: did you solved your question? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Instead of package get if you save pubsec.yml file ctrl+s it will save without any issue and your import error will remove after get dependencies.